# Release an App on a new account

Tags: iphone, release, multiple-accounts

So I have this App in the store, and I would like to release it on another account, newly created. Is anything like a transfer possible? Or would I have to remove it, and re-release it? Would that result in problems with Apple?

Does anyone have any infos about this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to transfer an app that is live on the App Store between iTunes Connect accounts. You'll have to remove the app from sale, upload it separately to the other iTunes Connect account and submit it as it was a new application.

The problems here are that users of the app that downloaded it originally will get no notification that it was removed or that it has been uploaded under a new account. So effectively you'll be leaving your entire user base behind and starting fresh.

Without some marketing, your users won't know that the app has moved. The app will also lose any reviews/ratings it has (good or bad).